# Wizard nested form using wicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, wizard

I have a nested form in a wizard. How can i perform the update action so that both the table gets updated at the same time. My form is:

```
<%= form_for(@web, url: wizard_path, :method => :put, html: {:class=>"form-horizontal, left"}) do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for resource.role do |rf| %>
    <%= rf.text_field :fname, :class=>"span5", type: "text", placeholder: "First Name", required: "" %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <%= rf.text_field :lname, :class=>"span5", type: "text", placeholder: "Last Name", required: "" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

where i have resource.role = "User".

My models are web and user.

I tried doing this but only web table gets updated:

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
include Wicked::Wizard
steps :personal, :organization

def show
    @web = current_web
    render_wizard
end

def update
    @web = current_web
    @web.attributes = params[:web]
    render_wizard @web
end
end
```

Please Help